# Track of new inserted document and execute specific event

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I have a collection of a `post` when a user comment on a post it will be maintain in an embedded documents of named `comments`.Now a problem is I have to sent a push notification at every `2 hours` like this `You have 12 new comments on this post` for an `owner` of this post.

Now after clicking on push notification it redirect me to that comments after `seen` those comments.Now if a new comments is against post then after 2 hours i will be getting like this `You have 3 new comments on this post`

You can see in my schema that i will maintain `total_comments` fields.Problem is how i managed this `push notification time based` and how to identify and maintain track record of new comments.Should i add some `key` in schema and write a `cron jobs` to send push notification

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my record

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57b3aa2db630347c1f9308b4"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2016-08-30T05:05:18.301Z"),
    "created" : ISODate("2016-08-17T00:05:01.354Z"),
    "createdTimeStamp" : 1471392301,
    "likes" : [],
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "created" : 1471935213,
            "user" : ObjectId("57b33c810a56a0a81a9b50b7"),
            "text" : "next party",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57bbf2edee7a923c156c2f08")
        }, 
        {
            "created" : 1471935612,
            "user" : ObjectId("57b33c810a56a0a81a9b50b7"),
            "text" : "its new party ",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57bbf47cddd701302ba14fca")
        }, 
        {
            "created" : 1471935717,
            "user" : ObjectId("57b33c810a56a0a81a9b50b7"),
            "text" : "its new again",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57bbf4e5f934024c275f4f08")
        }, 

    ],
    "total_comments" : 3,
    "consumer_id" : ObjectId("57b33c810a56a0a81a9b50b7") // Original User that receive notification 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to count new comments I guess.

**First :**

Storing in your user schema a key `lastVisit`.
And then do something like `db.posts.count({'comments.created': { $gte: $$$YOUR lastVisit$$$ }});`

`comments.created` must become a date.

**Second :**

Storing a key `read: boolean` in comments and false by default.
Then every time a user read the notification change this value to true.

And then count the new comments like this `db.posts.count({'comments.read': false})`

Then I don't know the best choice between a `cron task` or a `setInterval`

Comment: if i have added the key `lastvisit` date then how it identify that at that time how much comments are are seen.As i maintain total_comments when a comment is added.and every time it send like `12 new comments on your post ` then if two new added then `14 new comments` as previous i visited `12 new comments` it should be `2 new comments`

Comment: Done hope, this will help you :)

Comment: i understand your solution.its not to much expensive that for every user i have to run `cron jobs` and then check `comments.read` and then send push notifications?Is there any flexible solution available ? did `socket` can reduce performance

Comment: Imo socket is the best way to do this! (it is what i've done). Btw you don't need a cron job for each user. just one job to do all.

Comment: Will you share something like this in `socket` for just getting an idea so i rebuild my architecture

Comment: It's a way too long to explain ^^ but just for giving an idea : send a socket to the post's owner every comments the new count if the owner is logged in, at the owner's login else.